# Add files properties to cpp file generated by automoc with cmake

Tags: qt, cmake

I am working on a Qt application, using `cmake` with `automoc` to deal with generating the Qt object classes.

My generated file `file_automoc.cpp` compiles with warnings. The warnings themselves come from a header file included in the cpp-file, but this header file is part of a third party lib which I cannot modify.

I would like to pass compile flags in order to suppress these specific warnings only for this file.

The problem is that I cannot use `set_source_files_properties` on the generated file, because `cmake` complains that the file does not exist.

How can I use `cmake` to pass the compile flags to the generated file before it actually exists on the file system?

Answer (score 1):

Including the lib with `SYSTEM` makes the compiler suppress warnings for this lib.

From https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/include_directories.html:

> If the SYSTEM option is given, the compiler will be told the directories are meant as system include directories on some platforms. Signalling this setting might achieve effects such as the compiler skipping warnings, or these fixed-install system files not being considered in dependency calculations - see compiler docs.

This change:

```
-INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES("/usr/include/thelib")
+INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(SYSTEM "/usr/include/thelib")
```

suppressed these warnings.